# Static IP for Ubuntu 13.10 Server (VirtualBox)

Tags: 13.10, virtualbox

I'm trying to change my Ubuntu VirtualBox (guest) to a static IP. I have a Bridged network enabled which allows me to easily SSH into the virtual box from my Mac.

When inside the Ubuntu virtual box, and I run ifconfig I get the following:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:01:64:ea
          inet addr:192.168.43.161  Bcast:192.168.43.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe01:64ea/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:163 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:124 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:17856 (17.8 KB)  TX bytes:14776 (14.7 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

The machine works fine, I'm able to access my URLs hosted on the box via Apache, and the box itself is also able to access the internet.

To convert to static, I'm editing my /etc/network/interfaces file and adding the following information:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
#iface eth0 inet dhcp

iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.43.161
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.43.1
```

I'm using the same IP address as given by ifconfig, and I acquired the IP address from the

```
route -n
```

command.

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.43.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.43.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

However, the moment I change to a static IP address this way, the virtual box loses the ability to connect to the internet.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you select an address outside the range used by the DHCP server in the router rather than copy over the same address. Also, you must specify DNS nameservers:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback


auto eth0
#iface eth0 inet dhcp

iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.43.200
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.43.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 192.168.43.1
```